# OOP - design, MVC

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, javafx

I want to create OOP - design of network application - text chat.
I use:

1. Java programming language
2. JavaFX platform as GUI
3. Model - View - Controller pattern

I divided my project to 3 separate packages: **Model**, **Controller**, **View**.
I also created class **NetworkConnection**, which is responsible to *create connection* to the server and *receive/send messages*.
I have several questions about application's design:

- Where should NetworkConnection class belong? Model or Controller? I have been considering make this class singleton and leave it in default package. But i heard this is not the best way in OOP - design.
- What is the best way to prevent NetworkConnection class from creating several instances? If there is not, what is the best place for this class in project in terms of OOP? Since this is not an object from modeling system (such as "Message", "Contact" or "Conversation") i have no idea where this class belongs in my application.

Comment: if you want a unique instance then the NetworkConnection class should be designed according to the Singleton pattern. You can consider creating a service layer and put that layer between the controllers and the data access objects. A user makes a request. The request reaches the controller, the controller calls the services to update/get model components and process them, then the controller forward control to a specific view to be rendered

Comment: Singleton in the default package is definitely not the way to go. I doubt you *need* or really want it to be a singleton anyway. Once you decide where it should go, either in the controller or a service IMHO, the others get what they need from it.

Answer (score 1):

design NetworkConnection using singlton design pattern, and it will be part of you utility which will be used in the controller.